# bcp utility asking me to enter different parameters i do not undertand

Tags: bcp

I am using BCP To export data from sqlserver 2008R2 Database Name Health,and a table name patient.The out of the query should be save in a textfile:ApplicantsName.txt located at:

```
 C:\Users\meuser\Desktop ApplicantsName.txt -C -T
```

After running the following query on the command prompt:

```
bcp "Select FirstName,LastName,PatientNumber from Health.dbo.Patient order by FirstName" queryout "C:\Users\meuser\Desktop ApplicantsName.txt" -C -T
```

It prompted me this:

```
Enter the file storage type of fiedl FirstName [char]:varchar
```

and then this:
      Enter prefix-length of field FirstName[2]:FirstName
I have been entering some values but i think the best is to know how it works.After some time of research on the internet, know using bcp utility is one fastest way to export or import data between instance to a file.I follow exactly the samples provided by MS [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190919.aspx) but i think i need some practical explanation. Can some guide me how to go about this and a little bit of explanation or relevant ref. will be appreciated too.

Answer (score 2):

`@one angry researcher`'s solution of adding '-C RAW' did not work in my particular case but adding lower-case '-c' did.  It [performs the operation using a character data type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/bcp-utility?view=sql-server-2017#c)

For instance:

```
bcp mydb.mytable out c:/temp/data.txt -T -c
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to add a value for the -C parameter (capital C!). If you do not know what you're using it for, you probably won't be needing it and can omitt it.

Refer to the official documentation: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162802.aspx

edit: you could, for example, use

```
bcp "Select FirstName,LastName,PatientNumber from Health.dbo.Patient order by FirstName" queryout "C:\Users\meuser\Desktop\ApplicantsName.txt" -C RAW -T
```

You will need to fix your output directory too (seems you forgot a backslash there).

Comment: that produces  this error:
SQLSTATE=S1000,NativeError=0
Error=Microsoft SQLSERVER Native Client 11.0 unable to open BCP host data-file

Comment: This could have either of two reasons: 1. you have the output file currently opened in another program (e.g. text editor) or 2. the path is invalid

Comment: @kombo: Don't try to write to your Desktop folder; the account that SQL Server runs under doesn't have write access there. Use a folder under `C:\Users\Public` instead that you create for the output (and can give access to if needed).

Comment: @MarcZilla, it display this:
Enter the file storage type of field FirstName[char]:    and i entered "c" it displayed :Enter prefix-length of Field FirstName[2]. This was what i entered from onset

Comment: @MarcZilla, your solution works, the problem was there was some fields with null value. I will now try to figure out how to handle such cases

Answer (score 0):

heres the sample bcp command with query and credentials (param)

```
bcp "SELECT * from yourtable" queryout c:\StockItemTransactionID_c.txt -c -Uusername -Pdbpassword -Sinstance -dYourDBName
```

*Note: -U -P -S are case sensitive.*